# McAfee found 2 viruses but could not fix automatic opening of unwanted firefox and chrome pages and javascript

Tags: windows-7, browser, virus, anti-virus

Having downloaded and installed a sound recording software which contained viruses causing unwanted web pages and javascript panels to pop up, I thought I would get rid of the problem by installing AVIRA, but that did not work. So I've just uninstalled Avira and installed the commercial software McAfee. Having run a complete 8 hour or more scan on my Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit coomputer, I now have ended up with the following window:

[image]

I can't believe the problem couldn't be fixed. I always thought McAfee could get rid of all PC problems. Now what? Am I stuck forever with these two viruses????

---

EDIT: Now I get it. McAfee would have blocked these programs before they could actually get installed had I installed it before running any programs from the Internet without checking out any comments by other users (and the program I downloaded that contained the viruses, called `Free Audio Converter 2015`, actually was the first result when I typed `free audio converters` in the google search box (an inorganic paid result). What a scam. Now these viruses have opened the door for many more viruses. I have even called McAfee support and they would only help me for a fee and would not offer free support, not even as a one-off, for my localized version of Windows. So now, my decision is: back up my user directory and reinstall everything from scratch!!!! (that will get rid of all viruses and malware for good), and install McAfee as soon as the Windows installation is finished.

Comment: There is not a single security software that can solve ALL PC problems nor is there a security software that remove ALL malicious infections.  You should first verify the infections found are not a false positive ( VirtusTotal ) helps with that.

Comment: Super User is an English-only site.  We appreciate the fact that you posted the exact output that you got on your screen, but, when it’s in a non-English language, it’s very helpful if you provide a best-effort translation into English.  (And, yes, I can guess that “Impossibile elimiinare” means “Impossible (or unable) to eliminate”, but it’s in your best interest to make your question easily accessible to as many people as possible.  And, speaking of accessibility, note that some of our users are blind; so, in fact, you should always provide a transcription of text in screenshots.)

Comment: To my knowledge McAfee does not offer phone support.  So I must warn you have trusted or allowing ANYONE remote access to your computer.